# Using Blade templating in HTML attribute

Tags: templates, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I want to dynamically change the attribute value for an HTML tag in a Blade template.

```
<span class="badge badge-blade-difficulty">
```

In the code above, I want to change blade to a value that can differ. I tried many things like

```
{{<span class=&quot;badge badge-$blogpost->difficulty&quot;>}}
```

or

```
<span class="badge badge-{{$blogpost->difficulty}}">
```

But these result in an error. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I totally understand your problem but as far as I can see, this could help.  (please include actual errors in your questions rather than "these result in an error")

To add the attribute as a data element from your app:

```
<span class="badge {{{ isset($difficulty) ? $difficulty : '' }}}">
```

(assuming the `class="badge"` is what you want when difficulty is not passed.  It's not clear from your question what the original value should be)

Your `View::make()` should pass the data to the view:

```
$difficulty = "badge-blade-difficulty";    
return View::make('viewname', $difficulty);
```

again... I am not totally sure this is exactly what you are looking for but it should get you going.